# problem with install pySFML pip install pySFML windows python 3.9, 3.7

Tags: python

I try to install

`(env_py) PS D:\github\env_py\Scripts> pip install pySFML`

After that I have:

`ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pySFML (from versions: none)`

`ERROR: No matching distribution found for pySFML`

I am using python 3.9 and 3.7  on windows
And there is the same problem

THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

The package [name seems to be `sfml`, not `pySFML`](https://pypi.org/project/sfml/#description).

Try

```
pip install sfml
```

Comment: (env_py) PS D:\github\env_py\Scripts> pip install sfml
Collecting sfml
  Downloading sfml-2.3.2.dev1.tar.gz (506 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 506 kB 198 kB/s 
ERROR: No .egg-info directory found in C:\Users\jacek\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-wn6yqevi

Comment: The package may be broken, then. You're not the only one having trouble. https://github.com/intjelic/python-sfml/issues

Answer (score 0):

pip install pySFML  doesnot work anymore. The best way is to download the wheel from the below link and install it through wheel file

```
https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pysfml
```

To install the wheel file just go to the directory where you have downloaded the file and then just do

```
pip install xyz.wheel
```

Comment: (env37) PS D:\github\env37\lib\site-packages> pip install pySFML-2.2.0-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl                                                                                                             
 ERROR: pySFML-2.2.0-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

Answer (score 0):

Another way, on linux
`sudo aptitude install python3-sfml`

It is work
I can

`import sfml`
but on windows I still can not install

Answer (score 0):

https://www.sfml-dev.org/download/bindings.php

Extract the archive, and copy the files to your installation of Python. If you don't know where it's located, by default it should be "C:\Python26" on Windows or "/usr/lib/python2.6" on Linux.

Once the files are properly installed, you're ready to use PySFML.amd following command
python setup.py build